pywsgi.WSGIServer SSL Certificate eroor with Flask
I generated a ssl certificate with openssl and wanted to add it to flask.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    http_server = pywsgi.WSGIServer(('0.0.0.0', 5000), app, keyfile='server.key', certfile='server.crt')
    http_server.serve_forever()

But when I request the ip of the server I get the error
ssl.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3874)
2024-04-27T13:03:44Z <Greenlet at 0x199436caac0: _handle_and_close_when_done(<bound method StreamServer.wrap_socket_and_handle , <bound method StreamServer.do_close of <WSGIServer, (<gevent._socket3.socket [closed] at 0x1994370ab00)> failed with SSLError

I expected beingable to request the server under https://{serverIP}:5000/

"I generated a ssl certificate with openssl ...." - there are many ways to generate certificates with openssl and many wrong ways too. It is unclear what exactly you did. "But when I request the ip of the server I get the error ..." - this reports only the error in the server. What kind of error do you get in the client? Please add all the details.
